# How set height for print content?

Tags: javascript, html, printing, stylesheet

i have:

```
function printContent2(div_id)
 {
     var content = document.getElementById(div_id);
     var map_src = window.open("", "PRINT MAP", "width=800,height=600,top=0,left=0,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,resizable=no");
     map_src.document.write('<html><head>');
     map_src.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/leaflet-0.5.1/0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>');
     map_src.document.write('</head><body>');
     map_src.document.write(content.innerHTML);
     map_src.document.write('</body></html>');
     map_src.document.close();
     map_src.focus();
     map_src.print();
  }
                           .mapstyle {
                               height: 100%;
                               height: -webkit-calc(100% - 69px);
                               height: -moz-calc(100% - 69px);
                               height: calc(100% - 74px);
                               margin-left: 420px;
                           }
  div id="map" class="mapstyle"
```

and after

```
printContent2('map');
```

show on full list.

I need set height = 400px.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

you ca use something like this:

```
   map_src.document.write("<html><head><style> #"+div_id+"{height:400px !important;font-size:12px;}</style>")
```

Comment: have you replaced yourId with the id of you div.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to add Div wrap**

```
function printContent2(div_id)
 {
     var content = document.getElementById(div_id);
     var map_src = window.open("", "PRINT MAP", "width=800,height=600,top=0,left=0,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,resizable=no");
     map_src.document.write('<html><head>');
     //map_src.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/leaflet-0.5.1/0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>'); ** Remove this line
     map_src.document.write("</head><body><div style='height:400px;border:1px solid blue;'>");
     map_src.document.write(content.innerHTML);
     map_src.document.write('</div></body></html>');
     map_src.document.close();
     map_src.focus();
     map_src.print();
  }
```

**Updated Answer:** I have Seen your code. It seems like there is an issue with your code . Just remove or comment below line and it's working for me.

```
 map_src.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/leaflet-0.5.1/0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>'); // Remove this Line.
```